# Show a selection of a dataframe in a new tab in a Shiny Application when clicking a button

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following Shiny application

## Server.R

```
library(dplyr)
library(rhandsontable)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 9*1024^2)

function(input, output) {

  values <- reactiveValues()

  Post <- c("", "")
  list2 <- c(12,13)
  df <- data.frame(Post, list2)


  output$contents <- renderRHandsontable({

    rhandsontable(df, width = 550, height = 300) %>%    
      hot_col(col = "Post", type = "dropdown")
  })

  saveData <- function(){
    finalDF <- hot_to_r(input$contents)
    newDF <- finalDF[complete.cases(finalDF),]
    return(newDF)
  }

  output$contentFinal <- renderRHandsontable(
    #finalDF <- hot_to_r(input$contents)
    return(newDF)
  )
  observeEvent(input$saveBtn, saveData())

}
```

## UI.R

```
library(rhandsontable)
fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Summary", rHandsontableOutput('contents'),
                           actionButton("saveBtn", "Save changes")
                  ),
                  tabPanel("Tab",
                           rHandsontableOutput('contentFinal'))



      )

    )
  )
)
```

What I try to accomplish it that - when I hit the save button in the summary tab I get an overview of the complete cases in the tab view.

So when I select a value in the first row of the database and I hit save changes it should pop up a selection of the dataframe in the next tab.

However the newDF file is create in the save is not found in the Tab. Any thoughts on how I can make sure the filter pops up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi change your server code this

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  values <- reactiveValues()

  Post <- c("", "")
  list2 <- c(12,13)
  df <- data.frame(Post, list2)


  output$contents <- renderRHandsontable({

    rhandsontable(df, width = 550, height = 300) %>%    
      hot_col(col = "Post", type = "dropdown")
  })

  saveData <- eventReactive({input$saveBtn},{
    finalDF <- hot_to_r(input$contents)
    finalDF <- as.data.frame(lapply(finalDF,function(Col){as.numeric(as.character(Col))}))
    newDF <- finalDF[complete.cases(finalDF),]
    return(newDF)
  })

  output$contentFinal <- renderRHandsontable(
    #finalDF <- hot_to_r(input$contents)
    rhandsontable(saveData())
  )
  # observeEvent(input$saveBtn, saveData())

}
```

[image]

hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. However now i get a complete copy. If I insert something a one of the two rows and press save I expect to see one row. Suggestions?

Comment: @HenkStraten Hi made a fix for that. the handsontable doen't have any `NA` as default.

Comment: does it work for you now? I still get an empty df... Also getting this error - Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: @HenkStraten I am sorry but I can't reproduce your error. I have added a gif of how it looks for me